# How can I display the output after hello?

Tags: assembly, mips

/*How can i display the name input after hello?? */

```
.text
.globl main
main:

la $a0, prompt   # load address of prompt into a0
li $v0, 4   # load instruction number to display string into v0
syscall     # system call to print the prompt call

li $a1, 81  # set string length 
la $a0, name    # get address of string variable
li $v0, 8   # service call number for reading string from keyboard
syscall     # Read string

la $a0, greeting  # Display the greeting message
li $v0, 4   # load address of greeting into a0
syscall     # call to system to print greeting call

la $a0, endl    # load new line into a0
li $v0, 4   # load call code number to display the string into v0
syscall     # call to system to print new line

li $v0, 10  # End of greeting program
syscall     # Call to system
```

/*is there a specific format or call for name*/

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "What's your name? "   #prompt user for name
name: .space 82 #directive to initialize number of characters in string
greeting: .asciiz "Hello, <name> ."
endl: .asciiz "\n"
```

Comment: First you would remove the `<name>` part of the `greeting` string, and then you'd use system call 4 to print the name.

Comment: If you are able to receive input and you are able to print a string, I'm not sure why you would be asking this question.

Comment: David yes i can output name but i can't figure which will add the input name to my string. so far, I've learned in java that 
    System.out.print("Hello "+ name);
will give me on the screen: Hello "name"
that's what i'm looking for in mips

Answer (score 0):

here is the full code after editing:

`enter code here`

```
.text
.globl main
main:
la $a0, prompt  # load address of prompt into a0
li $v0, 4   # load instruction number to display string into v0
syscall     # system call to print the prompt call

li $a1, 81  # set string length 
la $a0, name    # get address of string variable
li $v0, 8   # service call number for reading string from keyboard
syscall     # Read string

la $a0, greeting# Display the greeting message
li $v0, 4   # load address of greeting into a0
syscall     # call to system to print greeting call

move $t0, $v0   # Moveing name from v0 into t0 for safe keeping

la $a0, name    # load address of name into a0
li $v0, 4   # load call code to display string into v0
syscall     # call to system to print name

la $a0, endl    # load new line into a0
li $v0, 4   # load call code number to display the string into v0
syscall     # call to system to print new line

li $v0, 10  # End of greeting program
syscall     # Call to system
```

###################DataSegment

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz " What's your name? "   #prompt user for name
name: .space 82 #directive to initialize number of characters in string
greeting: .asciiz " Hello, " # Display input next to Hello
endl: .asciiz "\n"
```

I only had to call name after i called greeting
Thanks Michael for pointing system call 4.